# Need help capturing text between quotes and embedded quotes in a string using regular expression

Tags: regex, parsing

Here is my code. I'm using RegexBuddy to test with:

```
"([^"]*)(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"
```

Here is a sample of what I'm testing with.

Strings with Embedded Qu
`\"The quick fox\" jumped over \"the lazy dog\"` returns:

`The quick fox\`

`the lazy dog\`

`"The quick fox" jumped over \"the lazy dog\"` returns:

`The quick fox`

`the lazy dog\`

Here is the problem I'm having: When capturing text between Embedded Quotes, the matched text has a backslash at the end. Can anyone tell me how to include it in the regex pattern above?

Thank you

Comment: where is the problem? Isnt it working as you want too? It should return everything between 2 quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\\?["][^"]+\\?["]
```

This will matches what are inside " and \", but the matches include " or \"

```
(?<=[\\]?")\S.*?(?=[\\]?")
```

This one will matches without any

`"` and `\"` , but it requires an space behind every `"` or `\"` in the text

Answer (score 0):

```
"([^"\\]+)\\"
```

Try this.See demo.Grab the capture.

http://regex101.com/r/pQ9bV3/6

Comment: That doesn't work at all in Regexbuddy. It captures each character.

Comment: @JimMacDiarmid it should work.See the demo i have posted

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to exactly understand what you are looking for, but you can try something like this:

```
"((?:[^\\"]+|\\[^"])*+)\\?"
```

Comment: @Casmir et Hippolyte That doesn't match anything. The problem I'm having is that when matching strings with embedded quoted text, there is a trailing backslash left at the end of the matched text.

Comment: @JimMacDiarmid: "That doesn't match anything": Strange, take a look at this: http://regex101.com/r/lO3tO2/1 . What regex engine do you use in regexbuddy?